# Using a comma with "and that" and so then" (adverb vs conjunctions): The human race has one really effective weapon, and that is laughter

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions, adverbial-phrases, optional-that, so

I saw many examples using "and that". I was confused with the use of a comma before it in the middle of the sentence. In the case of independent sentences, some examples do not have a come like " Mr Berry said the timing was a coincidence and that his decision was unrelated to Mr Roman's departure". On the other hand, there were examples that use commas before independent clauses like "The human race has one really effective weapon, and that is laughter. Mark Twain ".

The confusion with "and that" and "so then" is that I couldn't understand when they can be considered as an adverb or conjunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"And" is a conjunction. There are two independent clauses here: "The human race has one very effective weapon", and "That is laughter." They are joined together with the conjunction "and". It would be completely grammatically valid to drop the "and" and make them two separate sentences.

No, "and" is not an adverb and is not being used as an adverb.